# jackson should only include inner attributes

Tags: java, json, jackson

Suppose  i have class like below:

```
public class X{

private Y y;
private String str;

//getters and settes

public static class Y{
   private Set<String> ids;

    public Set<String> getIds() {
        return ids;
    }

    public void setIds(Set<String> ids) {
        this.ids = ids;
    }
}

}
```

Now i am serializing a object `X` then i get something like below:

```
{"str":"val", "y":{"ids":["1e2a921f","1e2a921h"]}}
```

What i want is `{"str":"val", {"ids":["1e2a921f","1e2a921h"]}}`. Actually i dont want `"y":` in the resultant json.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

```
X x = new X();
Y y = new Y();
y.setIds(<someVal>);
x.setY(y);
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(x);
```

Comment: You cant have {"str":"val", {"y":"val2"}} because this one is not a valid json!
Well maybe you can change the serialize function, but you will have problem trying to work with an invalid json object

Comment: Ideally it should generate `{"y":{"str":"val2"},"str":"val"}`

Comment: I think the logical explanation to him understand is: what about you had two attributes of type Y on that X class? How would you know, with your sintaxe, which one is for which attribute ?

Comment: try @JsonIgnore annotation from class com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation;

Comment: You have some problem with the concept of json, search about json format, if i dont make any mistake, you can not have anonymous objects in json, so always will be "name":value and value can be another json object, primitive value, array, or function